# "Snowflake not defined" error in Setup up of Snowflake-python connector in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I sucessfully installed and setup Anaconda Navigator withb python 3.7, launched Jupyter Notebook and can run Python 3.7.

Next, I installed the python-snowflake connector using ...

```
*pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python*
```

Then I start up Anaconda, open a jupyter notebook and use the sample connector code (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-install.html) with parameters set as shown.
I get a error message `ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob'`

How should I go about fixing this? Do I need to set some more environment parameters in Anaconda before launching Jupyter Notebook? If so how?

[image]

Comment: If you are on Azure, make sure to add that to connection, like `xxxxx.east-us-2.azure`

Comment: This may seem simple, but your picture doesn't indicate that you ran the import step in Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks Mike Walton - but I am not sure how to add the Snowflake environment in Anaconda so that its available to the laucnhed jupyter notebook. Can you advise how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't execute the first cell in your notebook, the one where you do `import snowflake.connector`. When you execute it, you'll see `In: [1]` to the left of it, while now it shows `In: []`. The consequence of this is that Python doesn't know what to do with the reference to "snowflake", and that's what the error message means.

If you don't have Snowflake's Python SDK installed, as your comment indicates, you can open a Anaconda prompt and run `pip install snowflake-connector-python`.

Comment: Thanks @d.hoeffer that sounded promising but I got this error when I tried ...

Comment: Added the error above - now I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob'"

Comment: That error was due to a problem with dependencies - it should be fixed in the current release. You can also do `pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0` to work around it.

Answer (score -1):

Defining connection details like this worked for me

```py
uname=''

pword=''

acct='xyz.us-east-1'

whouse=''

# connect to Snowflake

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(

    user=uname,

    password=pword,

    account=acct
    )
```

Comment: thanks @abhi reddy but that did not work for me (I still get "NameError: name 'snowflake' is not defined" )